# Hive / Hadoop: Monitor the running processes

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

Is there anyway to monitor running Hive processes and ensure that they are indeed working in parallel?

I have setup an experimental Linux cluster (4 machines) and would like to understand the underlying processes.

top and ps don't give me too much info.

Comment: What do you want to monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive query is divided into several MR called sql_text-stage 1, sql_text-stage-2 etc. 
You can enter UI of your cluster's JobTracker web UI  on 
job_tracker_adress:50030  
 There you will see hive jobs and their progress. 
For each job there will be list of tasks and for each task you can see on which nodes they are running, and their basic statistics